# how to prevent main thread ios from killing background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a method in my `AppDelegate` that saves a `NSManagedObjectContext` passed as a parameter. This method may be called on either the main thread or a background thread, and I want to ensure that when this method is called the main thread doesn't kill it halfway through when the user terminates the program or what have you. How do I prevent the main thread from killing this thread when this method is being executed?

I also want to do this for writing data to a plist file -- this also may happen outside of the main thread.

I am doing all my background work by way of GCD and `dispatch_async`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad Larson had some suggestions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6653110/793607) that should help you.

In your appDelegate, when your app is getting pushed to the background, it calls `applicationDidEnterBackground`.  From this routine, you can see if your method is currently in progress, and can behave accordingly.

Depending on how long your task takes to run there are two options:

1. If it will take significantly less than 5 seconds, you can just have your `applicationDidEnterBackground` wait until your task is completed before releasing.  If you take longer than 5 seconds, your app will just get force-killed.
2. If it could be a while, you can try  `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`: to start a background task that finishes off your task.