# How to determine app is in active state or inactive state ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, lifecycle, user-inactivity

I need to know when an App is in Foreground, it is in active state or inactive state ?

If my App is in inactive state I need to fire the Logout Protocol and destroy the current user's session,

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"App is not active logout success");
}
```

Is there any appDelegate method which tell me that app is in inactive state, any code example will help me a lot.

If need work with  "NSNotificationCenter", in which class can I add the code and who will be observer.

Comment: Default App delegates in the template already provide what you need. Read the comments within the functions.

Comment: @Tchami How is that a duplicate if the question is about iOS?

Answer (score 8):

To test for the state you can do something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]==UIApplicationStateInactive
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]==UIApplicationStateActive
```

If you want to be notified you can do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(yourselector:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

or

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(yourselector:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

You can do other notifications too (from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/):

> UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
>   UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
>   UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
>   UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
>   UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
>   UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
>   UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable
>   UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable
>   UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification
>   UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
>   UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
>   UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
>   UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
>   UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
>   UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
>   UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification

If you want to use the app delegate, you can use:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {}
```

or

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, you have solved my problem 50%, I need a little bit more help, I need the something which is opposite to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` like `UIApplicationDidBecomeInActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillBecomeINActiveNotification`

Comment: I updated my answer.  You can use UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification.  An app goes through background before becoming inactive.

Comment: Great answer :) Definitly found some useful stuff for everyday use in there

Comment: Yes I know these things, but none one of them is worthful to me. Let me Tell u scene, 1) App launches (**App is always in Foreground never goes to background**) 2) suppose for time being (say _60sec_) App does not receive any event from user. 3) It means after _60sec_ App comes to **inactive** state. 4) After _60sec_ (in **inactive state**) i m going to fire the logout protocol.

Comment: You might find this helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650717/when-an-ios-application-goes-to-the-background-are-lengthy-tasks-paused. You can run background task in background for 10 minutes. Perhaps you set a timer for 60 seconds and then call your logout method , unless the app becomes active again?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this Apple Doc :[App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

`applicationDidBecomeActive`:—Lets your app know that it is about to become the foreground app. Use this method for any last minute preparation.

`applicationWillResignActive`:—Lets you know that your app is transitioning away from being the foreground app. Use this method to put your app into a quiescent state.

`applicationWillEnterForeground`:—Lets you know that your app is moving out of the background and back into the foreground, but that it is not yet active.

`applicationWillTerminate`:—Lets you know that your app is being terminated. This method is not called if your app is suspended