# GCD background task maximum TTL

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I need to be able to program background tasks. Little "crons" if you will, that execute some simple code. While not being an expert in GCD I was wondering:

1. What is the maximum time I expect for the background task to actually perform its duties in the background before apps quits completely
2. Can I "program" multiple tasks and expect them to complete in timely order
3. Are they only active as long as the app is launched? ( I bet they are, unlike local notifications that dont really care whether the app is running in the background or not, so just asking to be sure)
4. How to I keep track of them and cancel if needed?

   For instance I able to do something like this and task is performed. I went as far as 1 minute here and it works.

   ```
   let backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 60) {
               // Some action here
               UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier)
   })
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does Apple permit a background task to run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275415/how-long-does-apple-permit-a-background-task-to-run)

Comment: Marked as a duplicate, I know you have several questions, but before you post multiple questions you should search for them individually and exclude the duplicates. When you do , edit your question and hit me up I will remove the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the time remaining for a given session using `backgroundTimeRemaining` (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623029-backgroundtimeremaining)). Apple makes no guarantees about what this time will be, it varies with battery level, hardware, resources, etc., so probably no good for a long running persistent background task. You might want to consider the [background fetch API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623100-setminimumbackgroundfetchinterva), although this is similarly throttled by iOS and you don't have complete control over when it runs.