# How can I check if someone has touched the iPhone home button?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin, monogame

How can I check if someone has touched the iPhone home button during gameplay?

I want to run some code before the iPhone switches from my game to the iPhone home screen.

Comment: See the willResignActive notification: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication+Notifications.ObserveWillResignActive/p/System.EventHandler{MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificationEventArgs}/

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650717/when-an-ios-application-goes-to-the-background-are-lengthy-tasks-paused) - You'll need to handle `applicationWillResignActive` rather than checking that the button is pressed

Comment: Thanx. I found out that I can use Game.Deactivated and Game.Activated in MonoGame.