# how to run code logic in the background in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift. Here is the following thing I am trying.

Track the location and motion status of the user in the background. When user's motion status goes from walking to running I want to track the location. And when the app comes to foreground I want to pin the tracked location where the user started running from walking.

It works fine when the app is in foreground entire time. But it does not work when the app is in background.

How shall I implement the code for the logic to be executed in the background?

Location service in the background:

[image]

Comment: What kind of location permissions have you requested, _When In Use_ or _Always_?

Comment: @EmilDavid Always

Comment: Have you turned on location updates in Background mode?

Comment: Yes location update in background is on.

Comment: Then I'd recommend in your _AppDelegate_ inside the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, to start a background thread to run your logic on. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6653110/4962554) explains a similar issue and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25070476/4962554) is a good intro for Swift threading.

Comment: Make sure the Background fetch is turned on as well in your app capabilities

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, select the target and go to the `Signing & Capabilities`tab. In the Background Modes section, check `Location updates`. This will allow the location tracking to be performed when your app in in background.

Of course make sure to request location Always (in the Info tab, and provide a description of the reason why you need the location in `Privacy - Location Always and When in Use Usage Description` and/or `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description`